# How to translate text into another language with HTML tags in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I want to translate the text, including text and HTML tags into a different language, but still retain the HTML tags, such as `<p> Have a nide day </ p>` into `<p> Passez une bonne journée nide </p>`; I know i can can translate manually using https://translate.google.com, but is there another way that I can send automatically the content to be translated to the page "https://translate.google.com" and get results returned by using PHP?.Thanks you very much.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/getting_started

Comment: Have you tried anything? Doesn't look like you've even Googled it.